# Crystal Reports not working with ApplicationPoolIdentity

Tags: visual-studio, iis, crystal-reports, applicationpoolidentity

I'm facing an issue currently where Crystal Reports are only working with "Local Service" or "Network Service" identities in Application Pool. If I switch to a "Custom Account" or ApplicationPoolIdentity, reports won't work and I'm getting "No printers are installed" exception. The same thing works perfectly when I switch the application pool identity to NetworkService or LocalService.

I need to use a custom account for each of my site on the server somehow. Can you please help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom account and added it in following user groups (lusrmgr.msc)

- Administrator
- Network Configuration Operators
- IIS_USRS

The only thing I was missing was, I forgot to login using this newly created account before assigning it to the application pool identity (custom account). Once I logged in, it was working fine and I didn't receive 'No Printers are installed' error anymore.

BTW, The reason I did all this was to resolve a desktop heap memory issue which was probably a reason of using 'Network Service' account to all my IIS websites which are around 20 on our server. There was a suggestion to use individual accounts for each of my website and crystal was stopping that.